# Writing a Pythonic prime sieve

Tags: python, beginner, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I'm practicing writing code less by brute force. I'd like feedback for writing a prime sieve more Pythonic, simpler, or more creatively perhaps.

```
def prime_sieve(limit):
    numbers = dict()
    limit = int(limit)
    for n in range(2, limit + 1):
        numbers[n] = ()
    primes = numbers.copy()
    for n in numbers:
        m = n
        while m <= limit:
            m = m + n
            primes.pop(m, 0)
    return primes
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your implementation of the sieve, using a dictionary, throws away many of the benefits of the approach; dictionaries are *unordered*. Even a naive list-based implementation ends up processing fewer than half as many numbers (146 vs. 382 with a limit of 100):

```
def sieve(limit):
    nums = range(limit+1)
    nums[1] = 0
    for n in nums:
        if n:
            for x in range(2*n, limit+1, n):
                nums[x] = 0 # counting this vs. pop
    return set(filter(None, primes))
```

Your approach processes multiples of numbers that will subsequently turn out to be non-prime themselves, e.g. you might pop all multiples of 9, then go back over them when you later process 3.

Note that I have used a `set`, which is effectively a dictionary with no values, rather than have some dummy value.

Also, there was no need to copy the whole dictionary; `for n in numbers.keys()` would have worked fine.

There are numerous other implementations, in Python and other languages, on this site and elsewhere; I suggest you look at a few to see what other alterations could be made.